# How to use bash tree command on a text file with directory listing

Tags: bash, tree

I have a text file with the directory listing of some folders like

```
./boost/1.75.0_2/.brew/boost.rb
./boost/1.75.0_2/include/boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp
./boost/1.75.0_2/include/boost/accumulators/accumulators_fwd.hpp
./boost/1.75.0_2/include/boost/accumulators/statistics.hpp
./boost/1.75.0_2/include/boost/container/node_allocator.hpp
./boost/1.75.0_2/include/boost/container/node_handle.hpp
./boost/1.75.0_2/include/boost/container/options.hpp
```

and I would like to use the [tree](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) command to obtain the following output with the directory structure:

```
└── 1.75.0_2
    ├── INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
    ├── README.md
    ├── include
    │   └── boost
    │       ├── accumulators
    │       │   ├── accumulators.hpp
    │       │   ├── accumulators_fwd.hpp
    │       │   ├── framework
    │       │   │   ├── accumulator_base.hpp
    │       │   │   ├── accumulator_concept.hpp
    │       │   │   ├── accumulator_set.hpp
    │       │   │   ├── accumulators
    │       │   │   ├── depends_on.hpp
    │       │   │   ├── external.hpp
    │       │   │   ├── extractor.hpp
    │       │   │   ├── features.hpp
    │       │   │   └── parameters
    │       │   ├── numeric
    │       │   │   ├── detail
    │       │   │   ├── functional
    │       │   │   ├── functional.hpp
```

I cannot access the file system, I only have the text file with directory listing. Is it possibile to use `tree` on that file?

Comment: Do you have enough rights to write to `/tmp` ? My idea is that you can recreate the file structure based on what you have in your text file, then run the `tree` command in it.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick hack, you could recreate the actual file structure (can be done anywhere; in `/tmp`, in a VM, or even on a remote machine) and then run `tree`:

```
mkdir tmptree
cd tmptree
sed 's/./\\&/g' yourFile | xargs mkdir -p
tree
cd ..
rm -r tmptree
```